# How to open an std::fstream (ofstream or ifstream) with a unicode filename?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

You wouldn't imagine something as basic as opening a file using the C++ standard library for a Windows application was tricky ... but it appears to be. By Unicode here I mean UTF-8, but I can convert to UTF-16 or whatever, the point is getting an ofstream instance from a Unicode filename. Before I hack up my own solution, is there a preferred route here ? Especially a cross-platform one ?

Comment: I this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480849/windows-codepage-interactions-with-standard-c-c-filenames) question. See if any of the answers there can help.

Comment: Why don't you use data types like `std::wofstream`? Notice the **w**!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The C++ standard library is not Unicode-aware. `char` and `wchar_t`  are not required to be Unicode encodings.

On Windows, `wchar_t` is UTF-16, but there's no direct support for UTF-8 filenames in the standard library (the `char` datatype is not Unicode on Windows)

With MSVC (and thus the Microsoft STL), a constructor for filestreams is provided which takes a `const wchar_t*` filename, allowing you to create the stream as:

```
wchar_t const name[] = L"filename.txt";
std::fstream file(name);
```

However, this overload is not specified by the C++11 standard (it only guarantees the presence of the `char` based version). It is also not present on alternative STL implementations like GCC's libstdc++ for MinGW(-w64), as of version g++ 4.8.x.

Note that just like `char` on Windows is not UTF8, on other OS'es `wchar_t` may not be UTF16. So overall, this isn't likely to be portable. Opening a stream given a `wchar_t` filename isn't defined according to the standard, and specifying the filename in `char`s may be difficult because the encoding used by char varies between OS'es.

Comment: A far more complete and up to date answer, including how to do this with g++, as well as other Windows API avenues, etc., is available in [a more recent thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23969243/464581).

Comment: @MichalM: no. `wchar_t` is of course just a 16-bit wide character type, which can be used to store anything you like. It doesn't care about encodings. But the Win32 APIs which accept `wchar_t` arguments expect them to contain UTF-16 data. The Windows API hasn't used UCS-2 since Windows 2000,

Comment: @MichalM: What is *is* (not what it's close to, but what is *actually* stored in a `wchar_t`) is a UTF-16 *code unit*. It's not UCS-2, and while it is close to UCS-2, it is closer still to a UTF-16 code unit (because that's what it actually *is*). UTF-16 specifies a code point to be represented by one or two code units, the latter being known as a surrogate pair.

Comment: This answer is obsolete since C++17.

Comment: really?      it's ofc present in minigw as of minigw is msvc copypaste

Comment: @jalf: you seem to know a lot about Unicode and C++. Do you offer a 2 or 3 day course where I could learn all about Unicode (ideally including Microsoft MBCS, Codepages and ANSI)? Or create a course on Pluralsight maybe (it doesn't have a unicode course)?

Answer (score 34):

Since C++17, there is a cross-platform way to open an std::fstream with a Unicode filename using the [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path) overload. Example:

```
std::ofstream out(std::filesystem::path(u8"こんにちは"));
out << "hello";
```

Comment: When I tried this on Windows the file created was named "ã“ã‚“ã«ã¡ã¯". (Source file saved as UTF-8). Are there other steps you have to perform to make this sample create a correct filename?

Comment: @thomthom When using C++17, it should be `std::filesystem::u8path(u8"whatever")`.

Answer (score 3):

The current versions of Visual C++ the std::basic_fstream have an `open()` method that take a wchar_t* according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dx08bh4.aspx.

Comment: Will this ultimately / theoretically be portable ?

Comment: Not all OSs and file systems support Unicode file names so it would not be portable. From what I can gather the wchar_t* open() and constructor on fstream are Microsoft extensions because NTFS does support Unicode file names.

Comment: or rather, because NTFS uses UTF16 to encode Unicode filenames. Linux supports unicode filenames too, but uses UTF8, so the regular char* version works there

Comment: are there no any options if MinGw compiler  is used?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::wofstream`, `std::wifstream` and `std::wfstream`. They accept unicode filename. File name has to be `wstring`, array of `wchar_t`s, or it has to have `_T()` macro, or prefix `L`before the text.

Comment: Could you provide evidence of `std::wfstream` being `Unicode`? Up to my modest knowledge, they just use `wchar_t` which is a wide character, usually `16-bits`. But the content could or not be `Unicode`.

Comment: What I meant is that they accept unicode strings, which answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually it answer half of the question: let's say you got your file path UTF16 in your wfstream (or UTF8 in your fstream). Windows do not accept unicode and will return "wrong url" if you have some special characters(e.g. Chinese).

Comment: How can windows not accept unicode? Are you talking about the first versions of windows? If anyone is still using them, they got bigger problems to solve.

Comment: You were probably right though. I just stumbled upon 2 cases where I had to write unicode characters with ofstreams and wofstream didn't help. I tried simple `file << L"фыв" << endl;`and not only it doesn't write it, it stops any further writing through the `file` stream. So I used winAPI's `WriteFile` instead.

Comment: `wofstream` uses `wchar_t` as its unit of information. It doesn't provide a constructor taking any string type based on `wchar_t`. If your compiler offers it, it's a non-standard extension. If that compiler is the Microsoft Compiler, you could use `ofstream` just as well. The non-standard extension is available to any `basic_ofstream` class template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Boost.Nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/):

```
#include <boost/nowide/fstream.hpp>
#include <boost/nowide/cout.hpp>
using boost::nowide::ifstream;
using boost::nowide::cout;

// #include <fstream>
// #include <iostream>
// using std::ifstream;
// using std::cout;

#include <string>

int main() {
    ifstream f("UTF-8 (e.g. ß).txt");
    std::string line;
    std::getline(f, line);
    cout << "UTF-8 content: " << line;
}
```

Comment: nowide works very nicely.... shame it is not in the standard boost distribution; but getting it to work is pretty straightforward.... great to be able to sidestep wchar at last :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt mixed with `std::ifstream`:

```
return std::wstring(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(qString.utf16()));
```

Note that the `std::basic_ifstream` constructor normally doesn't accept a `const w_char*`, but [on in the MS implementation of STL it does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-ifstream-class?view=msvc-160#requirements). With other implementations you would probably call `qString.utf8()`, and use the `const char*` ctor.

Comment: There is no `ofstream` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) that takes a `std::wstring` argument. This appears to be an answer to a different question.

Comment: This is still inaccurate. The additional `basic_ifstream` constructors are a Microsoft-specific extension to their C++ library implementation. Other compilers for Windows may or may not provide those. Regardless, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842261/1889329) explains you don't need to worry about character encodings, or which constructor to use at all. Just pass a [`filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) and have it work on any OS.

Comment: @IInspectable Updated again. Not everyone can use C++17. My answer was intended to help people who use Qt.

Comment: If you cannot use C++17 or Microsoft's C++ Standard Library implementation then there aren't any safe alternatives. Passing a UTF-8 encoded string for any given platform is either not safe, or documented to not be safe, or documented to be safe. Consider yourself lucky if you are in the latter two categories, though realistically you'll find yourself in the first. In that case the recommendation to use `utf8()` is almost malevolent in that it frequently doesn't fail.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't know what you want from me. Is there anything you think needs to be done? Why are you using a word like "malevolent"? That's not a constructive way of working towards a common goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wfstream
```

instead of

```
fstream
```

and

```
wofstream
```

instead of

```
ofstream
```

and so on...
You can find this information in the [iosfwd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) header file.