# Opening a text file with fstream but filename characters are not in ASCII

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open an std::fstream (ofstream or ifstream) with a unicode filename ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename)

I want to open a text file using c++ fstream but the character used for the filename didn't fall in ASCII character set.
for example :

```
 fstream fileHandle;
 fileHandle.open("δ»Wüste.txt");
```

Is there way exist in through which I could open file with such names.

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: @Ephphatha See, the Description of this question correctly. Its not Duplicate to that.

Comment: It looks identical to me but I'll answer it anyway.

Comment: File names are inherently system specific, and depends on what the underlying file system supports. The language cannot define that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question [How to open an std::fstream with a unicode filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename) @jalf notes that the C++ standard library is not unicode aware, but there is a windows extension that accepts wchar_t arrays.

You will be able to open a file on a windows platform by creating or calling open on an fstream object with a wchar_t array as the argument.

```
fstream fileHandle(L"δ»Wüste.txt");
fileHandle.open(L"δ»Wüste.txt");
```

Both of the above will call the wchar_t* version of the appropriate functions, as the L prefix on a string indicates that it is to be treated as a unicode string.

Edit: Here is a complete example that should compile and run. I created a file on my computer called `δ»Wüste.txt` with the contents `This is a test.` I then compiled and ran the following code in the same directory.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int, char**)
{
  std::fstream fileHandle(L"δ»Wüste.txt", std::ios::in|std::ios::out);

  std::string text;
  std::getline(fileHandle, text);
  std::cout << text << std::endl;

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
This is a test.
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: I need this with fstream. I have gone through the last post also related with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking sorry, the example I provided works for me on a windows system and uses fstream.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use long strings:

```
fileHandle.open(L"δ»Wüste.txt");
```