# MinGW C++: Reading a file with non-ascii file name

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, mingw, fstream

Simple task: I want to read a file which has a non-ascii file name.

On linux and MacOS, I simply pass the file name as a UTF-8 encoded string to the `fstream` constructor. On windows this fails.

As I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename), windows simply does not support utf-8 filenames. However, it provides an own non-standard `open` method that takes a utf-16 `wchar_t*`. Thus, I could simply convert my `string` to utf-16 `wstring` and be fine. However, in the MinGW standard library, that `wchar_t* open` method of `fstream` simply does not exist.

So, how can I open a non-ascii file name on MinGW?

Comment: It appears this may not be possible: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567893/fstreamopen-unicode-or-non-ascii-characters-dont-work-with-stdiosout?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567893/fstreamopen-unicode-or-non-ascii-characters-dont-work-with-stdiosout?rq=1)

Comment: @owacoder: I cannot read a non-ascii file on MinGW? That would be hilarious. That would be a super harsh restriction which basically makes MinGW useless for countries in which non-ascii characters in names are common (basically more than half of all countries on earth). Thus, there simply has to be a way.

Comment: I meant using fstream directly. There are surely many workarounds using other methods (direct system-specific calls, for sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue before. Unfortunately, until you can use `std::filesystem::path`, you need to work around this in some way, e.g. by wrapping everything, e.g.  like I did [here](https://github.com/rubenvb/architekton/blob/master/file.c%2B%2B#L196), which makes "user code" look like this:

```
auto stream_ptr = open_ifstream(file_name); // I used UTF-8 and converted to UTF-16 on Windows as in the code linked above
auto& stream = *stream_ptr;
if(!stream)
    throw error("Failed to open file: \'" + filename + "\'.");
```

Ugly yes, slightly portable, yes. Note this does not work on Libc++ on Windows, although that combination is currently not functioning anyways that doesn't matter much.

Comment: how would a solution with `std::filesystem::path` look like? Isn't that class already available as experimental extension?

Comment: It is, in the newest builds. I believe MSVC also has support of some form of filesystem, no idea if they're compatible. I can't find anything except the [technical specification](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0218r0.html) and it seems to imply Windows will stay quite broken if I'm reading it correctly :/.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can give [Boost.Nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/) a try. It has a `fstream` wrapper which will convert your string to UTF-16 automatically. It is not yet in boost, but already in the [review schedule](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) (and hopefully soon part of boost). I never tried it with mingw but played around with visual studio and found it quit neat.

Comment: If I introduced such a not-stable-yet dependency to our project, my manager would kill me ;).

Comment: @gexicide I see.... than probably a more professional library [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/). But i never tried it, so i cannot say if it meets you requirements.

Comment: Has ICU a way to open an fstream from an UTF-16 object? We already use ICU, but just converting to UTF-16 is not enough, as I miss the fstream constructor that takes it.

Comment: @gexicide hmmm... that's odd. I thought converting the string to UTF-16, putting it into a wide-char string-variant and using the wide char variant [std::wifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) could work. But, as i said, i never tried it, since i try to avoid any widechar/ UTF-16 stuff, and try to use only UTF-8.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't :). I don't want a `wifstream`. The `wifstream` assumes the *file contents* are multibyte chars. But that is not the case, only the *file name* is unicode. The constructor of `wifstream` therefore also takes a `char`, not a `wchar_t`. There is no `wchar_t` constructor - at least not on MinGW or linux.