# C++ std::stringstream/ostringstream and UTF characters

Tags: c++, utf-8, stringstream, ofstream, ostringstream

I'm writing a program which processes some data, outputs it to a .csv file, then writes a GNUplot script, and calls GNUplot to execute the script and create an image file all with the same name (only different extensions). The filenames contain UTF characters (UTF-8 I believe?) such as °, φ and θ. All of this works perfectly fine when I compile and execute it in Linux with g++ 4.4.7. I then altered my code to compile in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, and the problems start when I run the program.

I use the following two bits of code to

1. Make a standard filename string (to which I just add extensions for the various files)
2. Open a stream to write to a file (the only difference between the GNUplot script and the .csv files is the extensions

   ```
   // Generate a file name string
   stringstream ss;
   ss << type << " Graph #" << gID << " - " << title;
   string fileName = ss.str();

   // Open a stream for the output file
   ostringstream outfile;
   outfile << fileName << ".gplt" << ends;
   ofstream ofs( outfile.str().c_str() );
   ```

The contents of the `ofstream` files where `ofs` writes contain the UTF characters properly, however the stringstream-created string `fileName` and the `ostringstream` created filename (even when not created with `fileName`, I tested it) show the characters incorrectly.

Example:

> What it should be - CDFvsRd Graph #32 - MWIR @ 300m, no-sun, 30kts, θ=all°.csv
>   What it ends up as - CDFvsRd Graph #32 - MWIR @ 300m, no-sun, 30kts, Ï=allË.csv

What can I do to remedy this, with as much standard C++ as possible? Would converting my `fileName` string to `wstring` help?

Comment: Is this related to the general topic of using C++ to access unicode filenames?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316672/opening-fstream-with-file-with-unicode-file-name-under-windows-using-non-msvc-co  Also this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158018/how-to-read-binary-file-with-unicode-filename-c

Comment: I suppose, and I had already looked at both of the pages you linked, but neither has an actual solution.

Comment: @pavichokche: [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) has some recommendations on how to deal with utf-8 reasonably under MSVC. Unfortunately I don't think you're going to find a nice solution.

Comment: Can you amend your question by adding hexadecimal dump both of the **output** and **source code** where the non-ASCII are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to write the Windows portion of the code to not export the filenames without the graph titles, omitting the UTF-8 characters from the filename. This wasn't a true solution, only a workaround.