# c++ UTF-16 ofstream file creation Windows

Tags: c++, windows, utf-16, ofstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open an std::fstream (ofstream or ifstream) with a unicode filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename)

I have a string encoded in UTF-16 and I want to create a file, where the name of the file would be this string.

UTF-16LE string looks like:

[image]

At first I want to make sure that system sees and displays correctly this name.

I try:

```
char *output=some address (points to memory where line is held)
ofstream out(output);
out.close();
```

On output I don't get proper name.
It looks like:  
[image]

For creating of the highlighted file I appended UTF-16LE mark, not highlighted file was created using just raw UTF-16 line - none of approaches works.

Are there some ways to create files with UTF-16LE names in Windows using only C++ functionality without WinApi (CreateFilew)?

My compiler is MinGW 4.0.4, Windows XP (but I want it to be working on all Windows)

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: I believe Windows uses UTF-8 on filesystem, so you'll probably need to convert the string to UTF-8.

Comment: they advice to use UTF-16 for everything  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , if I'm not wrong

Comment: Carl Norum, I cannot use solution from there, because string is not known in advance, http://i.imgur.com/zTtL8.png .  I cannot declare my line as  wchar_t line[], size may be any

Comment: ...`wstring str = [...]; std::fstream file(str.data());`...

Comment: @AlexanderShulz you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as

Comment: Griwes, plz, could you be more precisely, what does mean wstring str=[...]  -? String is held in char *line; String ISN'T known in advance, it's NOT contant.  If I try to do as you offered  I get   http://i.imgur.com/ZHwLR.png   , did I get you right?  Moreover as I know  fstream can't accept wchar_t type. What do I misunderstand?

Comment: http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all guys, but it seems that C++ streams are helpless in this case (at least I got such opinion).

So I used WinApi:

```
 #ifndef WIN32    // for Linux
   ofstream out(output);
   out.close();
 #else  // for Windows
   LPWSTR lp=(LPWSTR )output;
   CreateFileW(lp,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ |  
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,     NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL );
  #endif
```

And  I got an output  file with a correct name:

[image]

Thanks again!