# C++ ifstream long full path not working

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to read a file from disk and during program execution using QDialog (Qt Widget) I choose the path to the file. Piece of code is very simple:

```
ifstream infile(path.c_str());

if (infile.is_open()) {
    //some code   
}
else
    //log it
```

The problem arises depending on the location of the target file:

- If the path to the file is "D:\folder\file" - it reads the file and
  everything is okay
- If the path to the file is "C:\Users\Rafał
  Surname\Desktop\folder\file" - file cannot be opened

How can this be solved ?

Comment: _'file cannot be opened'_  You may want to use the [`std::ifstream::exceptions()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) member to get more information what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray: the answers there are very incomplete, and the selected solution is old and therefore includes information that is incorrect now: "there's no direct support for UTF-8 in the standard library".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At a guess, your machine's Windows ANSI (the codepage returned by `GetACP`) does not contain the character `"ł"` in your name.

The simplest solution is to not use such character in the path.

Otherwise you can use *wide paths*, `wchar_t` based paths. Visual C++ support them even though standard C++ does not.

Alternatively, to make the code work also with g++, you can use the Windows API to translate the wide path to a *short path*, where each name is maximum 8 characters. The short folder and file names are alternates intended precisely for compatibility with non-Unicode software. However, while that works nicely and easily for the case at hand, namely opening a file, it's more complicated for creating a file.

Finally, you can use Boost filesystem, which is very similar if not identical to the functionality that will become part of C++14. And apparently a version/variant is already part of the Visual C++ runtime library. A problem with that is, however, that it may not work with g++, since it relies on the aforementioned wide path support in Visual C++ (yes, it's almost a paradox, getting libraries with such requirements in the standard).

---

There is some low level Unicode path support in g++'s standard library implementation, but not anything like offering `wchar_t` based constuctors. I delved into some old code of mine and found the code below. `cppx::Syschar` is a type defined by my code, and it has `wchar_t` as underlying type in Windows:

*File "open_file.h"*

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>      // fopen        !!!Needs to be first for g++ 4.7.2.
#include <rfc/cppx/core/Syschar.h>      // cppx::Syschar etc.
#include <wchar.h>      // _wfopen

namespace x {
    using cppx::Syschar;

    inline auto open_file( char const* const path, char const* const options )
        -> FILE*
    { return ::fopen( path, options ); }

    inline auto open_file( wchar_t const* const path, wchar_t const* const options )
        -> FILE*
    { return _wfopen( path, options ); }

    inline auto open_file( Syschar const* path, Syschar const* options )
        -> FILE*
    { return open_file( raw( path ), raw( options ) ); }
}  // namespace zx
```

*File "ofstream.g++_compiler.h"*

```
#pragma once
#include "open_file.h"                  // open_file
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>          // __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf

namespace x {
    using cppx::Syschar;

    class ofstream
        : public std::ofstream
    {
    private:
        __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char>  buf_;
        std::streambuf*                 p_original_buf_;

    public:
        ~ofstream()
        {
            basic_ios::rdbuf( p_original_buf_ );
            buf_.close();
        }

        ofstream( Syschar const* const filename )
            : std::ofstream()
            , buf_(
                open_file( filename, CPPX_U( "w" ) ),
                std::ios_base::out
                )
            , p_original_buf_( nullptr )
        {
            p_original_buf_ = basic_ios::rdbuf( &buf_ );
        }
    };

}  // namespace x
```

Of course this is an `ofstream`, not an `ifstream`.

And again, it's just an example of the support in g++, while the answer to your question most likely involves either using the wide path support in Visual C++, or using the Windows API, or simply avoiding Unicode-specific characters, as discussed above.

Leveraging the Visual C++ wide path support a similar `ofstream` implementation can simply be like this:

*File "ofstream.msvc_compiler.h"*

```
#pragma once

#include <rfc/cppx/core/Syschar.h>      // cppx::Syschar etc.

#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

namespace x {
    using cppx::Syschar;

    class ofstream
        : public std::ofstream
    {
    public:
        // Other stuff, and ...
        ofstream( Syschar const* const filename )
            : std::ofstream( raw( filename ) )   // wchar_t, a Visual C++ extension.
        {}
    };
}  // namespace x
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of that slanted "l" in your path. It's a Unicode character. There's a current problem with Unicode in paths. [As far as I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename), only `open()` method of streams in Visual Studio accepts `wchar_t*` paths.