# How to output MODULEENTRY32 properties data types?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a module snapshot and I got MODULEENTRY32 struct which contains data, which I would output like this:

```
   _tprintf( TEXT("%6d %-15s %s\n"),pe.th32ProcessID,me.szModule,me.szExePath);
```

Now lets say I would want to use that path, which is WCHAR me.szExePath and another method requires a path of const *char. How could I handle that, would I need to convert data type?

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is "other method parameters"?

Comment: Sorry, lets say as ezExePath is WCHAR, anf ifstream src... requires a parameter of const *char, which is path, how am I able to handle this, convert the WCHAR to const, or what? Thanks!

Comment: Then it depends on what you want to do. To open a file with a Unicode (WCHAR) filename, [you can just pass it to the constructor like usual, as a Microsoft-specific extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821873/how-to-open-an-stdfstream-ofstream-or-ifstream-with-a-unicode-filename)

Comment: Do stop using tchar.h, there has not been any point to it for over a decade.  You use use %ls to always match wchar_t*, %hs to always match char*.

Comment: Thank you, as I'm farily new to c++ that does help a lot =)

Comment: You go all in and use Unicode everywhere.