# Read and write binary files with UTF-8 file names on windows (with QT)

Tags: c++, utf-8, filenames, ifstream

I am trying to read and write to files with `UTF-8` file names such as files with Arabic or Persian names ("سلام.jpg") in C++. I am using the following code and it works fine on *nix systems (I checked it up on Android NDK). But it fails on Windows. This code snippet just tries to read the length of the file via `tellg` but on Windows it tells that file isn't open and `tellg` returns -1. I am using QT MingW so the VS `open` doesn't apply for me.

```
QString inFileAdd)
this->inFileAdd=inFileAdd;

ifstream infile;
infile.open(this->inFileAdd.toUtf8().constData(),ios::binary|ios::in|ios::ate);
infile.seekg (0, infile.end);
cout<<"is open: ";
if(infile.is_open()){
cout<<"true"<<endl;
}else{
cout<<"false"<<endl;
}
this->size=infile.tellg();
cout<<this->inFileAdd.toUtf8().constData()<<endl<<"file Len:"<<this->size<<endl;
this->fileContent=nullptr;
infile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`ifstream` (and `ofstream`) simply does not support UTF-8 file paths on Windows <sup>1</sup>.

However, at least in Visual Studio, they have *non-standard* constructors (and `open()` overloads) that accept `wchar_t*` file paths, so you can convert your UTF-8 to UTF-16 (or, in your case, just use `this->inFileAdd.toStdWString().c_str()` instead) to open files that use Unicode paths/names.

<sup>1: Windows 10 has experimental support for UTF-8 as a user locale. Programs can manually opt-in to enable UTF-8 in ANSI-based APIs, like `CreateFileA()`, which `ifstream`/`ofstream` are likely to use internally.</sup>

Comment: I already tried `this->inFileAdd.toStdWString().c_str()`. It works even with `.toStdString` in *nix systems but it fails on windows. I am using QT MinGW. Is there any option available for me?

Comment: Sounds like `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` in MinGW do not support opening files using `wchar_t*` strings. You might consider [using `Boost::nowide::ifstream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48518953/65863) instead. Or else construct a [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) from your `QString` and then [construct the `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` from that `path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842261/65863) (though, 1 person had a problem with that).

Comment: `std::ifstream` doesn't support `path` neither. I'll try `boost`.